# 'Unable to locate package.' when installing linux-headers

Tags: apt

I'm trying to make a wifi driver work and the instructions say to paste the code one line at a time. Does this mean hit <kbd>enter</kbd> after each line? How do I move down a line?

When I paste the first line and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, I get: `Unable to locate package.`

I am trying to enter four lines of text to make the code work:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
cd Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to install the necessary prequisites, build-essential amd linx-headers-`uname -r` it is necessary to have a working internet connection. Please be sure the ethernet is connected and working. Please type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Those tickmarks are on the left side of my US keyboard on the same key with ~. Press Enter and let the download and install finish. Now type:

```
cd ~/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012
```

Press Enter. Now type:

```
make
```

'make' will take a few moments, please be patient. If it ends in an error, stop as all further steps will also be in error. Post the error here so we may assist. If it finished without error (warnings are probably OK), type in:

```
sudo make install
```

Give your password when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that we have one more way also , placing the total code in one single line with proper format ,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` ; cd Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012 ; make ; sudo make install
```

Comment: It actually works if you just copy/paste the whole block of text on multiple lines as well.

Comment: Hey, I added the semicolons and it worked! But the connection is so slow it's unusable. Back to the forums to try again... Thanks!

Comment: @user225474 for slower connections you might switch to better update server from software sources.

Comment: @user225474 can you please mark the answer above as `answered`, since it works!